# Ubuntu Install on Lenovo ideapad Flex 4 - Help!

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, lenovo, ideapad

I've never had such tumult as part of any install...

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS on a Flex 4 with --

- Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz × 2
- 2gb RAM
- Intel® HD Graphics 500 (Broxton 2x6)

The system was running Windows 10 before I got a hold of it. Prior to trying to install Ubuntu, I entered he BIOS and selected the legacy configuration option so I could boot from a USB (pen drive, finger drive). I then had no problem booting to the USB, from which I chose to try the OS without installing it. Everything worked fine with the Flex 4's hardware, so I chose to install Ubuntu.

I guess I wasn't paying attention because I created a Live install on the USB, which is working great, thank you. However, I could not boot from the Flex 4's hard drive, of course. So I then installed Ubuntu to the hard drive. It seemed to install without issue, but I still can't boot from that darn hard drive.

Weirder yet, from the Live install, the OS sees the Flex 4's hard drive as if it were attached storage. In fact, the OS can see the fact that all the OS folders are in place.

I went searching the Net and found many potential solutions, most of which were from previous versions of Ubuntu. However, I did find this web page with a potential solution: [How To Fix Your BIOS After Installing Ubuntu 17.10 On A Lenovo Laptop](http://dailylinuxuser.com/2018/01/how-to-fix-your-bios-after-installing-ubuntu-17-10-on-a-lenovo-laptop.html). You'll note that the version of Ubuntu in question is 17.10, not the LTS version I'm trying to get to work. However, the article's counsel seems good, but....

If I understand the instructions in the article, I will be updating the Linux kernel. I'm  not an expert in Unix-based systems, but the kernel doesn't include a system BIOS, right? If I am correct in that assessment, is updating the kernel really the thing to do?

It's not clear to me that any BIOS is in place on the hard drive at this point, although, during the boot process, I am prompted to choose from options I could proceed with, like Grub2, the Live USB with Ubuntu, and the hard drive. If I choose the last of these options, the computer displays "Booting..." and never gets any further. If I choose Grub2, I'm prompted to choose from the same set of choices as before, but using a nicer font.

I need some guidance from here. Right now the only thing saving me is the fact that I have a Live install of Ubuntu on a USB to work from.

Answer (score 0):

cscottrun4it, the primary disk does not have a bios, it has a master boot record.  You could try to return your bios on the computer motherboard to the non legacy UEFI mode to see if that helps.  I am not too familiar with the Windows master boot record but if you have a recovery CD and instructions that might at least restore the boot from Windows if you set it up for dual boot which would require shrinking the Windows disk partition using Windows disk manager and installing Ubuntu on the vacated space.  If you overwrote Windows, then the problem lies in the data on the master boot record on the hard disk.  You might try to reinstall Ubuntu if Windows is gone.  When you reboot after the installation, you need to remove the USB thumb drive when prompted.  The data in the master boot record is what the system uses to boot the installed OS(s).  Here is one website on how to repair it.

https://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/